# Calculate area within a buffer zone

Tags: buffer, area, shape-area

I am working on 3.12.0-București.
I have created buffers (radius=300 meters) on a set of sampling points.
I do not remember the number of segments that I have used. However, I have set a high number of segments in order to have a buffer resembling to a circular shape. I am working in the CRS WGS 84/UTM zone 32N - EPSG: 32632

I have tried to calculate the area of these buffers (in squared meters) using the field calculator $area (see figure)[image: Buffer zone].

I have noticed:

1. The value of the calculated area is different for each buffer even if I have created all the buffers using the same settings;
2. The calculated area is always slightly different from the area of a circle with radius = 300 meters: probably this is because the shape is not "strictly" a circle

See the coloumn of the area buffer (each row represents a different buffer).

[image]

Could you clarify these two points?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the GIS software in use. Are you seeing differences of square meters? Square millimeters? At the limits of floating-point representation? A pair of examples would help.

Comment: Can you show us an image of those *buffers created using the same settings*?

Comment: where abouts are the points in relation to the edges of the UTM zone

Comment: If the exact area is important then use PI*300*300 - if it isn't then don't worry